# Where does the blue wire in my fan go to?

Tags: electrical

I took my fan down because it was not working..... I cleaned it thoroughly, and recut all the wires.  I checked everything and it worked fine.  Next, I went to fully assemble it, (knowing that the motor was working now) and a blue wire fell out of the fan motor itself.  I know where to connect it to the ceiling, However I do not know where this blue wire goes to the fan box itself....

Answer (score 1):

It connects the house wiring to the light kit if the fan has one, if the fan does not have a light, it does not need it, it is just a spare wire.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack said - usually for a light - if you have a light, I'd try to trace the light wiring inside the fixture and find where it broke off of.